# What is the function of getClass("nonlinear_fit") in growth rate estimation package?

Tags: r, package

Good day. I was just curious about the code functions in this growth rate package by Thomas Petzoldt (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/growthrates/vignettes/Introduction.html). Particularly about the function of this code:

```
getClass("nonlinear_fit")
```

I am wondering why I am encountering an error when I change the code to:

```
getClass("nonlinear")
```

I am attaching the code as how I use it and the exact error message I am getting below:

```
setClass("nonlinear", representation(
fit = "modFit", par = "numeric", FUN = "function_growthmodel", obs = "data.frame", rsquared = "numeric"
))
getClass("nonlinear")
getClass("nonlinear_fit")
obj <- new("nonlinear_fit",  fit = fit, par = c(parms, fixed.p)[parnames], 
FUN = FUN, obs = obs, rsquared = r2)
obj2 <- new("nonlinear",  fit = fit, par = c(parms, fixed.p)[parnames], 
FUN = FUN, obs = obs, rsquared = r2)
plot(obj)
plot(obj2)
```

Below is the console output:

> Extends: "growthrates_fit"
>
> > obj <- new("nonlinear_fit",  fit = fit, par = c(parms, fixed.p)[parnames],
>
> - FUN = FUN, obs = obs, rsquared = r2)
>
> > obj2 <- new("nonlinear",  fit = fit, par = c(parms, fixed.p)[parnames],
>
> - FUN = FUN, obs = obs, rsquared = r2)
>
> > plot(obj)
> >
> > plot(obj2)
>
> Error in as.double(y) :
>
> cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Comment: From the code example it remains unclear why you try to use `getClass`, `setclass` and `new`. This is part of the internal object orientation of the package, not intended for typical users. If you want to provide an own nonlinear model, you may consult [part 2](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/growthrates/doc/User_models.html) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells, that the code misses an appropriate plot function for your self-defined class.

A short explanation: if one defines a new class, here class "nonlinear", one needs to make sure to provide also methods for it. The error message shown above results from the fact, that if no `plot` function for class "nonlinear" was found, method dispatch will call R's default `plot.default` function that expects at least one numeric first argument (i.e. `double`, y) as it is not designed for a complex S4 object.

More about the S4 class system can be found in the book of Chambers, M. (1998), or in brief in chapter The S4 object system of Hadley Wickhams book [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/), and in many other places.

As said, it is absolutely not necessary to understand the S4 OOP details for using the package, even if one wants to define an own nonlinear model.

### References

Chambers, J.M. (1998) Programming with Data. A Guide to the S Language. Springer, New York.

Wickham, H (2019) Advanced R, Second Edition, Chapman & Hall/Crc the R Series.